# A Template engine written in PHP that use JSON format as data?

Tags: php, json, template-engine, mustache.php

I need a Template engine written in PHP that use JSON file as it's data. The popular engine that I love it's template format was [Mustache.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki) but what I understood from it's documentation, data for this engine is PHP classes that is not very pretty format.

What I need is something like this:

`Data in JSON` + `{{A Pretty Template that use curly braces for objects}}` = `A clean HTML`

And of course I want this engine to do the compiling on the server. Your comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `json_decode` function to decode JSON data into PHP Objects, like:

```
require '/path/to/mustache/src/Mustache/Autoloader.php';
Mustache_Autoloader::register();

$mustache = new Mustache_Engine();

$tpl = $mustache->loadTemplate('foo'); // loads __DIR__.'/views/foo.mustache';
echo $tpl->render(json_decode('my_data.json'));
```